# Unbiased estimator for negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, negative-binomial

**Exercise:**

A biased coin has a probability $p$ that it gives a tail when it is tossed. The random variable $T$ is the number of tosses up to and including the second tail.

Show that $\frac{1}{T-1}$ is an unbiased estimator of $p$.

**My work so far:**

I know that $P(T=t) = (t-1)(1-p)^{t-2}p^2$ for $t \ge 2$.

I know that $E(T) = \frac{2}{p}$.

I found a similar question at [Finding an unbiased estimator for the negative binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407997/finding-an-unbiased-estimator-for-the-negative-binomial-distribution), but I don't understand the first line (!) of the solution, which states:

$$E\left(\frac{r-1}{Y-r-1}\right)=\sum_{y=0}^\infty \frac{r-1}{y+r-1}\binom{y+r-1}{y} \theta^r(1-\theta)^y$$

Can someone please explain where the above expectation expression comes from?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \operatorname E\left( \frac 1 {T-1} \right) = \sum_{t=2}^\infty \frac 1 {t-1} \Pr(T=t) = \sum_{t=2}^\infty \frac 1 {t-1} (t-1)(1-p)^{t-2}p^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & p^2 \sum_{t=2}^\infty (1-p)^{t-2} = p^2 \times \text{sum of a geometric series} = p^2 \times \frac{\text{first term}}{1 - \text{common ratio}} \\[10pt]
= {} & p^2 \times \frac 1 {1-(1-p)}
\end{align}

Comment: This makes sense to me. It's actually just the first step that wasn't occurring to me; the rest is straightforward. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$Y$ takes nonnegative integer and

$$E(g(Y))=\sum_{y=0}^\infty g(y) P(Y=y)$$

Here $g(y)=\frac{r-1}{y+r-1}$ and $P(Y=y)=\binom{y+r-1}{y}\theta^r (1-\theta)^y$.

Comment: Could you be more informative? Why does $E(g(Y))$ take this value?

Comment: it is Definition 1.1 in this [document](https://imai.princeton.edu/teaching/files/Expectation.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Sample over all possibilities using your $P(T = t)$:

$$\sum_{t=2}^\infty (t-1)(1-p)^{t-2}p^2 \frac{1}{t - 1} = $$
$$\sum_{t=2}^\infty (1-p)^{t-2}p^2 = $$
$$p^2\sum_{t=0}^\infty (1-p)^{t} = $$
$$p^2\times\frac{1}{p} = $$
$$p$$